# Make a github repository depend from another one

Tags: github

This might be a silly question (or probably doesn't make sense at all).
I have two repositories (say `A` and `B`), basically `A` has some opengl code and `B` has some algorithms implemented.

They've been two different projects so far, but now I realize I could use some stuff in `A` to debug some stuff in `B`.

I don't know if it is possible but can I reference somehow `A` from `B`?
Apart from listing explicitly some dependency in the `README.md` I mean.

I think the idea would be every time `A` is updated somehow `B` is notified or anything that can explicit the dependency.

Again I don't know how people usually treats these cases, apart from listing an explicit dependency in the documentation, so mine is more a general question.

Comment: in a CI/CD workflow, `B` does not directly depend on `A`'s code. Instead `A`'s code is built, packaged and versioned and `B` depends on that particular binary version. This is probably a workflow you can adopt. does that answer your question?

Comment: I suppose it does, what do you mean with "packaged" exactly?

Comment: By 'packaged' I mean you build your code, then when you get a binary you put it in a shared location from where your other codebase an access it. Note that this is different for languages like Javascript where you have no binary. In that case you could put the code itself (say) into a zip, assign it a version number and use that package

Comment: Consider C++ as a language. I'm not sure what you mean with "shared location", do you mean locally?

Comment: For other languages, we typically use package managers. Basically what you do is in `B`'s codebase you say  _this requires version X of A_. Then you use a package manager like Conan to download your package from a server (https://docs.conan.io/en/1.4/uploading_packages/remotes.html). I understand that this could be confusing in the beginning but this approach will help you split dependencies in the future. The advantage is you can test them separately